# Laravel 5.3 - Route not defined, maybe because of same name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I keep getting a problem (route not defined) to be specific, when loading my web pages.

This is my route (Mainly focusing on the bottom 2 routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function()
{
    Route::get('/', function ()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('home');

    Route::post('/signup', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
        'as' => 'signup'
    ]);

    Route::post('/signin', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
        'as' => 'signin'
    ]);

    Route::get('logout', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getLogout',
        'as' => 'logout'
    ]);

    Route::get('profile', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@profile',
        'as' => 'profile'
    ]);

    Route::post('profile', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@updateAvatar',
        'as' => 'profile'
    ]);

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
    {
        Route::get('/dashboard',[
            'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
            'as' => 'dashboard',
            'middleware' => 'auth'
        ]);
    });

    Route::get('charities', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@charities',
        'as' => 'charities'
    ]);

    Route::resource('charities','charityController');

});
```

As they have the same name, I think maybe that this is causing an error but I am not quite sure.

User Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\HTTP\Controllers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\HTTP\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Image;
use Input;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getDashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');
    }

    public function postSignUp(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'name' => 'required|max:100',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'
        ]);

        $email = $request['email'];
        $name = $request['name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']); //bcrypt = hash password

        $user = new user();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();

        Auth::login($user);

        return redirect()-> route('dashboard');
    }

    public function postSignIn(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']]))
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function getLogOut()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }

    public function updateAvatar(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('avatar'))
        {
            $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
            $filename = time(). '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($avatar)->resize(300,300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatar/' . $filename) );

            $user = Auth::user();
            $user->avatar = $filename;
            $user->save(); 
        }

        return view('profile', array('user' => Auth::user()));
    }

    public function charities()
    {
        return view('charities');
    }
}
```

?>

CharityController contains the following function:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $charities = charities::all();
        return view('charities', ['charities' => $charities]);
    }
```

This is the link to the charities page:

```
<a href="{{ route('charities') }}"> Charities </a> </li>
```

This is the variable I used when iterating over the charities in my database:

```
@foreach ($charities as $charity)
```

The error I see is:

> Route [charities] not defined. (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\webproject\resources\views\profile.blade.php)

When I comment out this line out of the routes:

> Route::resource('charities','charityController');

Then the error disappears and the profile page works as normal, and vice versa.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: `Route::resource('charities','charityController');` already contains `get routes` and you defined before

```
Route::get('charities', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@charities',
    'as' => 'charities'
]);
```

So you can remove this `get` or you can keep it if it's necessary and then give your naming to  `Route::resource('charities','charityController');`

like:

`Route::resource('charities', 'AdminUserController', ['parameters' => [
    'charities' => 'admin_user'
]]);` then it would consider as `/charities/{admin_user}`  For more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes

Hope it make sense

Comment: Rahul, how do you mean split the route?

Comment: @Jay, I updated my answer, with ref. link. hope it will help you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should remove these lines

```
Route::get('charities', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@charities',
    'as' => 'charities'
]);
```

and use this route in the view

```
<a href="{{ route('charities.index') }}"> Charities </a> </li>
```

As you seem to be making redundant routes and controller functions. Since charities is a resource controller these are the routes available

```
charities.index
charities.create
charities.store
charities.edit
charities.update
charities.destroy
```